# GMFBridge source filter doesn't receive frame

Tags: c#, video, directshow, directshow.net

I have a webcam and I want to start/stop video recording without stopping the renderer. That's why I want to use GMFBridge. My graphs are:

```
Webcam -> FFDShow -> SampleGrabber -> Infinite Tee -> Color Converter -> Renderer

                                                   |---> GMFBridge Sink Filter

GMFBridge Source Filter -> Color Space Converter -> Encoder -> File Writer
```

I do everything like documents (InsertSinkFilter, InsertSourceFilter, BridgeGraphs, etc.) but GMFBridge Source Filter doesn't receive any frame.

The GMFPreview sample in [DirectShow.NET samples](http://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/files/DirectShowSamples/2010-February/) works but it uses RenderStream function to prepare the graph. The only difference between my code and GMFPreview is I manually add my filters and connect their pins and start the graph (I don't use RenderStream function).

What should I do to receive frame in GMFBridge Source Filter?

Comment: Does the renderer work? How do you know the GMFBridge Source Filter does not receive samples? (ie can't there be a problem with the encoder or file writer?)

Comment: Yes, the renderer works but the other branch doesn't. I don't think it's about encoder or something, because I changed the renderer part with the encoder part and then my recording became successful but renderer was black.

Comment: I solved the problem and posted it below. Now my renderer filter is in separate graph which gets frames via GMFSourceFilter. The problem is: when I move window to another monitor, graph stops and doesn't start. Why graph doesn't start automatically? And how can I detect this situation and run graph again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe how stupid mistake I made. I used to do bridge graphs with `ICaptureGraphBuilder` instances:

```
Bridge.BridgeGraphs(Graph_builder, Graph_builder2);
```

but actually I should bridge the graphs with sink filter and source filter parameters:

```
Bridge.BridgeGraphs(Graph_BridgeSinkFilter, BridgeSourceFilter);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first step in debugging this would be to enable graph registration in the JoinFilterGraph methods and make sure (using Graphedt to connect to the remote graph) that the pins are connected the way you expect.

Then, create a log file — create an empty file gmfbridge.txt in My Documents, run the app, and look at the log to see how far the delivery gets.

Comment: I checked both graphs using "Connect to Remote Graph" option of GraphEdit and there was no problem. Based on the log file, pin receives frame but disconnects. I uploaded the log file to here: http://tny.cz/0dc4c458

Comment: By the way; thank you very much for your answer Mr. Davies. I appreciate your help.